# Way to distinguish dynamodb TransactionCanceledException

Tags: node.js, error-handling, amazon-dynamodb

I have an api with transaction which uses DynamoDB as the database. I will be getting two kind of exceptions. One is due to **ConditionalCheckFailed** exception when the condition is not met. The error object looks like this:

```
{
    "message": "Transaction cancelled, please refer cancellation reasons for specific reasons [None, ConditionalCheckFailed]",
    "code": "TransactionCanceledException",
    "time": "2020-01-22T05:46:32.756Z",
    "requestId": "UG14A08TDB6Q5CADF0NH9JQAB3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 32.837614849025734
}
```

Another scenario is when I do the load testing on the same api, I will be getting **TransactionConflict** exception.

```
{
    "message": "Transaction cancelled, please refer cancellation reasons for specific reasons [None, TransactionConflict]",
    "code": "TransactionCanceledException",
    "time": "2020-01-22T05:54:40.940Z",
    "requestId": "87MHRV37F3G3EUUF629AKICARBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 31.786748424710908
}
```

I want to retry the transaction  on error due to  **TransactionConflict** exception.But I am not sure how to conditionally retry the transaction with this error information. Since the message part is the only key which tells me the exact reason of the error and not the error code itself.

I don't think comparing the message is a good way to conditionally handle error.

Answer (score 5):

> *I don't think comparing the message is a good way to conditionally handle error.*

I agree completely, but:

- AWS is very good about not changing APIs, so you are *probably* okay with this approach, and
- they don't appear to have given you any alternative.

A safe approach, I would suggest, is to string-match the message, but also to throw your own exception if you get a `TransactionCanceledException` with a message that *doesn't* match any expected string -- don't simply test whether it is equal/not equal to one possible string, but instead test it for all known/relevant values and if it matches no known pattern, halt and catch fire.  That eliminates the risk of unexpected changes to the text of the error silently causing your code to misbehave.

Comment: My research into the problem seems to reflect this sentiment as well.  The exception itself carries very little useful info beyond the noted string it was instantiated with.  It's a completely maddening characteristic of AWS tooling, but I think you're right that this is unlikely to change.  So now if you want to write an intelligent app, you get to parse out an "array" of errors in the string and try map them back to the multiple actions your transaction contains.  Fun.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know all 400 errors from DynamoDB are `NON retry-able`. 
It means that there is a issue with the way the API request is received and its not right and hence the 400 Error.

So, in your case, I would suggest fixing the issue and then adding a retry when you receive a retry-able exception. For more reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html

Only 500 errors are retry-able.

Comment: This isn't precisely correct, because OP is referring to a higher-level retry, where the application code says "Hmmm, TransactionConflict? That might be transient, so I want to craft a new, identical request, and attempt this same operation again." There is a probability that it will subsequently succeed, so is not a "retry" in the sense discussed in the docs. *"You have to fix the issue in your application before submitting the request again"* doesn't apply here because the request isn't wrong, it just collided with another request attempting a conflicting transaction at that instant in time.